# Getting specific word from doc file respective of uppercase/lowercase using python?

Tags: python

I am getting following output : `[[], [], ['Audi'], ['audi'], ['AuDi']]`
But I want `['Audi','audi','AuDi']`
my code is:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document(r'C:\Users\aliassample02.docx')
list1 = []
for para in document.paragraphs:
    results = re.findall(r'audi', para.text, re.IGNORECASE)
    list1.append(results)
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `extend` list instead `append`:

```
list1 = []
for para in document.paragraphs:
    results = re.findall(r'audi', para.text, re.IGNORECASE)
    list1.extend(results)
```

Or you can flatten values in list comprehension:

```
list1 = [x for para in document.paragraphs 
           for x in re.findall(r'audi', para.text, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

EDIT:

```
list1 = []
for para in document.paragraphs:
    for x in list2:
        results = re.findall(x, para.text, re.IGNORECASE)
        list1.extend(results)
```

Comment: @kumaranuj - Can you be more specific?

Comment: one more thing, if "audi" will be an iterable item then?
Like i want to iterate so many items like list2 = ["audi","bmw"]. Then i need to apply 

for i in list2:
    results = re.findall(r'i', para.text, re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: @kumaranuj - What should be output? both lists together?

Comment: I have one docx file and i want to delete/replace the particular word in docs which i will pass through as list.
list1 = ["aaa","bbb"]
wherever this two elements will be there in docx , it will delete and replace as well irespective of uppercase/lowrcase.
for delete operation i thought of using replacing it with "" empty string. and replacing i am using "replacingWord"

Comment: @kumaranuj - I think the best is create new question.

Comment: Ok. After 90 minutes, i will post it again. Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259624/how-to-replace-any-word-in-ppt-using-python-respective-of-uppercase-lowercase 

@jezrael can you please check.

Comment: @kumaranuj - I check it and not easy test, because there are no data for test, missing [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You can [flatten the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) after finding all things you want:

```
list1 = [item for sublist in list1 for item in sublist]
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
list1 = []
for para in document.paragraphs:
    results = re.findall(r'audi', para.text, re.IGNORECASE)
    list1.extend(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [item for sublist in list1 for item in sublist]
```

This list comprehensive also works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [x for para in document.paragraphs 
           for x in re.findall(r'audi', para.text, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Best solution i have got for my query.